# Python3 dictionary key unique method or callback

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am placing constructed objects in a dictionary as `key` and then assigning values (in a `list`).

Coming from C++, I am used to specifying how the `hash` is calculated to ensure uniqueness.

In this particular case I can see that the dictionary is using an address, and *hope* this doesn't clash with my intents.
However, I can't seem to find an answer to a simple question:

**How can I specify the key functor or callback** for an entry in a Python3 dictionary?

For example, suppose I want objects of the same class stored as a key, aside from the memory address, if I was to use `type(class_name)` that would be an issue, as different objects would have the same type?

For example:

```py
calls   = {}
# some loop
for x in z:
    obj  = class_name()
    calls[obj] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Would not be an issue, but the following would be:

```py
calls   = {}
for x in z:
    obj  = class_name()
    calls[type(obj)] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Explicitly I suppose I could use a function:

```py
def calc:
    # compute the key here

calls  = {}
for x in z:
    obj  = class_name()
    calls[calc(obj)] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Whereas in C++ I would have defined that in `std::unordered_map<key, value, hash_func<value>>;`
where the `hash_func` would specify how to calculate the actual key for the map, given a *key*.
Is there a similar mechanism in Python, or does it not make sense?
Maybe by subclassing `dict`?

Comment: python's dict implementation is clever enough to resolve hash collusions. the beauty of python is you don't normally need to worry about these things

Comment: @Chris_Rands I can believe that, I'm just a bit uneasy as to what happens behind the scenes when I know I will be passing objects that may collide.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. The problem with the second snippet is not "hash collisions", it is that you are using an identical key every time, ie the class.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood, if you just want to insert the same key multiple times without overwriting data then checkout `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: If it's possible for two distinct instances of your class to be considered equal, you need to define `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` on the class.  If all instances are unequal to each other, the default implementations of those methods are fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to be able to specify how the key is calculated when passing an Object, in a transparent way without explicitly calling the hashing function every time.

Comment: @jasonharper so that is how the class specifies the hash that will be passed to the `dict`?

Comment: @Ælex It's clear what you're asking, it's not clear what issue you're trying to solve, because it looks like there's no issue here.

Comment: As Jason says you can define the special methods to customise the hash calculation, but that still won't help because you are using the same key each time. You would have exactly the same problem in any other language.

Comment: @ChatterOne my issue is that I'd like to pass as key objects of same type, which specify internally how they are `keyed` or `hashed` so that it is explicit as part of the class design or dict design.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No I wouldn't, if I specify how the hash is made, each class can use extraneous parameters or members to create a unique key. The lookup can thus be on members, functions and not the object its self. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Ælex Yes, as I said that part is clear. Why you would want to do that is not clear. I understood that you want the actual index to be in the object itself, but the question is what advantage would that give you? What matters in the end is that you are able to store / retrieve your data in an efficient way, without messing without the underlying data structure, I guess?

Comment: @ChatterOne I think jason has given me the answer I was looking for. The reason is that I'd want an access key that is uniform and clear (e.g., the class name) but control over how that key is calculated and used. I am starting to see that in Python that doesn't make much sense. I'll delete the question, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question, based on what jasonharper suggested.
I don't know if this is the most *pythonic* way of doing stuff (it feels more similar to a c++ approach) but the end result was what I needed:
- a dictionary, who's key creation is defined by me:

```py
class pdf_to_text:
    #
    def __call__(self, filename):
        assert filename is not None, "None filename arg"
        doc         = None
        try:
            doc = Document(filename)
        except Exception as e:
            print('code: {c}, msg, {m}'
                  .format(c = type(e).__name__, m = str(e)))
        #
        words = 0
        lines = []
        for page in doc:
            for line in page.lines:
                lines.append(line)
                words += len(line.split())
        return (words, lines)

    #
    def __hash__(self):
       return hash(type(self).__name__)

    #
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (type(self).__name__ == type(other).__name__)

class pdf_to_ocr:
    #
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args
        obj = ocr(args)
        assert obj is not None, "OCR object was None"
        self.ocr = obj

    #
    def __call__(self, filename):
        return self.ocr.run(filename)

    #
    def __hash__(self):
       return hash(type(self).__name__ + json.dumps(self.args))

    #
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.__hash__() == other.__hash__())
```

Which now means that when using any of those instantiated objects as keys, it won't be their memory, name or other key that makes them unique, but the overridden `__hash__` method.